# Паттерн MVVM. Как обратиться к объекту модели

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть программа. Она из себя представляет таблицу (DataGrid) в которой мы можем удалять/добавлять строки, а так же менять значения в столбцах/строках (их 8).

Код пытаюсь строить с использованием паттерна MVVM. В коде есть 3 класса:

- Line:INotifyPropertyChanged - представляет из себя "шаблон" строки, обрабатываем изменения параметров в столбцах. Объекты этого класса хранятся в коллекции класса M1Model;

```
public class Line: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int? _number;
    private string? _type;
    private float? _alpha;
    private float? _height;
    private float? _radius;
    private float? _tickness;
    private float? _refraction;
    private float? _opticalForce;

    public int? number { get => _number; set { _number = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    public string? type { get => _type; set { _type = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    public float? alpha { get => _alpha; set { _alpha = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    public float? height { get => _height; set { _height = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    public float? radius { get => _radius; set { _radius = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    public float? tickness { get => _tickness; set { _tickness = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    public float? refraction { get => _refraction; set { _refraction = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    public float? opticalForce { get => _opticalForce; set { _opticalForce = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }

}
```

- M1Model:BindableBase - хранит в себе коллекцию из строк, команды для добавления/удаления строк и методы для математических операций со значениями в строках/столбцах;

```
public class M1Model : BindableBase
{
    public readonly ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Line> lines;

    public M1Model()
    {
        lines = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Line>(_lines);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Line> _lines = new ObservableCollection<Line>()
    {
        new Line() { number = 0 }
    };

    public void AddRow(int index)
    {
        _lines.Insert(index, new Line());
        for (int i = 0; i < _lines.Count; i++)
        {
            _lines[i].number = i;
        }
    }

    public void RemoveRow(int index)
    {
        if (_lines.Count > 1)
        {
            _lines.RemoveAt(index);

            for (int i = 0; i < _lines.Count; i++)
            {
                _lines[i].number = i;
            }
        }
    }

    public void UpdateAll()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _lines.Count; i++)
        {
            Alpha();
            Height();
        }
    }

    public void Alpha()
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < _lines.Count(); i+=2)
        {
            _lines[i].alpha = _lines[i - 2].alpha + _lines[i - 2].height * _lines[i - 2].opticalForce;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < _lines.Count(); i+=2)
        {
            _lines[i].alpha = (_lines[i - 1].alpha + _lines[i + 1].alpha) / 2;
        }
    }

    public void Height()
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < _lines.Count(); i+=2)
        {
            _lines[i].height = _lines[i - 2].height - _lines[i].alpha * _lines[i - 1].tickness;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < _lines.Count(); i += 2)
        {
            _lines[i].height = _lines[i - 1].height;
        }
    }
}
```

- M1VM:BindableBase - хранит ссылку на модель и команды;

```
public class M1VM : BindableBase
{
    readonly public M1Model _model = new M1Model();

    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Line> allLines => _model.lines;

    public DelegateCommand<int?> AddRow { get; }
    public DelegateCommand<int?> RemoveRow { get; }

    public M1VM()
    {        
        AddRow = new DelegateCommand<int?>(i => { if (i.HasValue) _model.AddRow(i.Value); });
        RemoveRow = new DelegateCommand<int?>(i => { if (i.HasValue) _model.RemoveRow(i.Value); });
    }
}
```

- Вьюшка (Control).

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:M1VM/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid >
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding allLines}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellEditEnding="dataGrid_CellEditEnding">

            <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="Insert" Command="{Binding AddRow}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid, Path=SelectedIndex}"/>
                <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding RemoveRow}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid, Path=SelectedIndex}"/>
            </DataGrid.InputBindings>

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding number, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="№" Width="40" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" TextBlock.FontSize="16"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding type}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Тип поверхности" Width="110" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" TextBlock.FontSize="16"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding alpha, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Угол луча (a)" Width="80" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" TextBlock.FontSize="16"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding height, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Высота луча (h)" Width="100" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" TextBlock.FontSize="16"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding radius, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Радиус (r)" Width="140" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" TextBlock.FontSize="16"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding tickness, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Толщина" Width="100" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" TextBlock.FontSize="16"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding refraction, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Показатель преломления (n)" Width="150" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" TextBlock.FontSize="16"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding opticalForce, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Оптическаяя сила (F)" Width="150" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" TextBlock.FontSize="16"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Возникла следующая проблема: после завершения "редактирования" ячейки, мне нужно провести математические операции во всей таблице (во всех строках). Узнать об изменении в ячейке я могу в классе Line. Но ссылка на модель хранится во VM. Каким образом можно уведомить M1VM или M1Model об изменении в Line? Или как можно обратиться из объекта Line к коллекции, в которой он хранится?

Comment: Лучше показывать код, чем красочно о нём рассказывать. Показывайте всё, о чём говорится.

Comment: @aepot, отредактировал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь всё просто. `ObservableCollection` имеет событие `CollectionChanged`. Подписавшись на него можно видеть события добавления и удаления элементов.

Каждый элемент коллекции имеет событие `PropertyChanged`, которое вы сами же вызываете в сеттерах свойств, то есть при их изменении. **Именно отслеживая эти события вью узнаёт об изменениях в данных.**

Можно написать вот такой обработчик:

```
private void OnLineChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Line line = (Line)sender;
    object value = typeof(Line).GetProperty(e.PropertyName).GetValue(line);
    Debug.WriteLine($"Line property changed: {e.PropertyName} = {value}");
}
```

Он просто покажет, какое свойство было изменено и с помощью рефлексии получит его значение.

Теперь чтобы при добавлении в коллекцию подписываться, а при удалении отписываться от изменений в `Line`, потребуется такой обработчик:

```
private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems?.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in e.NewItems.Cast<INotifyPropertyChanged>())
            item.PropertyChanged += OnLineChanged;
        Debug.WriteLine($"Lines added: {e.NewItems.Count}");
    }

    if (e.OldItems?.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in e.OldItems.Cast<INotifyPropertyChanged>())
            items.PropertyChanged -= OnLineChanged;
        Debug.WriteLine($"Lines removed: {e.NewItems.Count}");
    }
}
```

Теперь прикрутить это добро к коллекции. Для начала нужно убрать создание нового элемента при объявлении коллекции.

```
private ObservableCollection<Line> _lines = new ObservableCollection<Line>();
```

Теперь в конструкторе подписаться и добавить убранный выше элемент.

```
_lines.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
_lines.Add(new Line() { number = 0 });
```

В противном случае он не отслеживался бы обработчиками.

Вот, собственно и всё. Вы ослеживаете любое изменение любого поля в коллекции, а также добавление и удаление элементов.

`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` выводит текст в консоль студии во время отладки приложения.

---

Теперь подсказки. `BindableBase` это и есть реализация `INotifyPropertyChanged` (из библиотеки Prism MVVM, верно?), то есть реализовать вручную смысла нет, получится так, приведу фрагмент:

```
public class Line : BindableBase
{
    private int? _number;
    // ... остальные поля

    public int? number { get => _number; set => SetProperty(ref _number, value); }
    // ... остальные свойства
}
```

Всё, больше ничего не надо, событие `PropertyChanged` и метод `OnPropertyChanged` убрать.

И последнее. Поля и переменные пишутся с маленькой буквы, а классы, свойства и методы - с большой буквы. А у вас свойства с маленькой, поправьте.

Получится:

```
number  - локальная переменная или аргумент метода
_number - приватное поле
Number  - публичное свойство
```

Так код будет легче читать.

Comment: Спасибо. Суть я понял. Про нейминг подсказку тоже осознал. Осталось несколько ууточняющих вопросов. Во-первых, BendableBase из библиотеки Prism. Но в нем, помимо `SetProperty()`, есть еще метод `RaisePropertyChanged()`. Не знаете, случайно, есть ли разница, что из этого использовать? Во-вторых, метод `OnCollectionChanged()` необходим? Т.е., если я удалю элемент коллекции, вмести с ним не удалятся и обработчики событий без посторонней помощи?

Comment: И третий вопрос. Я правильно понимаю, что `_lines.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;` привязывает коллекцию к обработчику. Соотв. можно взять любую другую коллекцию и одновременно с этой привязать ее к обработчику?

Comment: @Хулиган `RaisePropertyChanged()` это то же самое что ваш `OnPropertyChanged`, точная копия. А про обработчики, почитайте про события и делегаты - как подписываться и отписываться от событий, разберётесь. Про OnCollectionChanged - верно поняли, ну это как бы из кода понятно и описания.